# Evaluate PHP through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, eval

**What I have and want to do**

- I have an `input area`.
- I have a JS script what reads the `input area`'s `innerHTML` and encodes it using `encodeURICompontent` then sends the value to `evaluate.php?code=+value`;
- I have an `evaluate.php` what `GET`'s the `code`'s value from the URL and returns an evaluated value using `eval($code)` to the javascript.
- And at the end it puts the `xmlHttp.responseText` to a `div`.

**But I get this error when the eval is executed:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Apps/editor/includes/exe.php(5) : eval()'d code on line 1

**Evaluate.php**

```
if(isset($_GET["code"])){
    $e = $_GET["code"];
    echo eval($e);
}
```

The value what I try to evaluate is just:

```
echo "Hello World!";
```

Then this is looks like in `$_GET["code"]` as:

```
echo \"Hello World!\";
```

Comment: It would really help to post the relevant code from evaluate.php.

Comment: Can we get your site's url so I can run `evaluate.php?code=system('rm -rf /')`? ;) Really, what are you trying to do? If `eval` is the answer, you're asking the wrong question (except in some very rare cases).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I edited my question, @delnan I'm really sorry but it's on my localhost, but you could try using the code what I put in my question under `evaluate.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PHP's documentation:

> eval() returns NULL unless return is
>   called in the evaluated code, in which
>   case the value passed to return is
>   returned. If there is a parse error in
>   the evaluated code, eval() returns
>   FALSE and execution of the following
>   code continues normally. It is not
>   possible to catch a parse error in
>   eval() using set_error_handler().

So I think there may be a problem when you run `echo eval($e)`.

P.S. It's best practice not to use double quotes in PHP unless a variable is contained within those quotes. For example, use `"Hello, $name"` and use `'Hello, Bob'`.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you have an error in a string you are tying to evaluate. Try to output it first and see if it has semi columns and things like that.

But you should never (!) evaluate code you get from URL! Never-never, anyone can send "exec('rm -rf /')".

Answer (score 1):

I feel terrible answering this. In your PHP settings, `magic_quotes_gpc` might be enabled which "corrupts" your incoming data by escaping it.

In order to get it working, you might want to add a little more insecurity to your undertaking by disabling magic quotes.

If that doesn't fix it, debug your input by following Silver Light's suggestions.

Comment: It's only on my localhost :P, hmm I don't really want to disable magic quotes because I need it for my other projects :\

Comment: So you **know** they're enabled? Then use `strip_slashes` on your incoming code.

Comment: did you mean `stripslashes`? The error is gone, but I don't have the result soo hmm :D WTF?

Comment: @goreSplatter Ups I modified the GET parameter sry :D hmm now it seems that works! however sometimes I get this error:

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Apps/editor/includes/exe.php(4) : eval()'d code on line 1`

Comment: As I see this is mostly because of spaces and new lines, but when I echo the `$e` before the eva it doesn't looks like it should have a problem about it :\ , I copied the echoed $e to the eval and works, wtf?